# After a DC loads the DNS zone does it ever have to contact the DNS server again?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller

I have a DC in a branch office.

The DC is pointed to another DNS server in a central office (**which is also a DC**) for its primary DNS.

So let me make sure I understand how this works:

When the DC boots up it goes across the WAN to pull down the DNS zone from the DNS server in the central office.

After it pulls down the DNS zone it shouldn't have to contact that DNS server any more right? It has the zone in memory it can use to serve requests.

Doesn't have to maintain a persistent connection to that DNS server in the central office or occasionally talk to it? Its not like its a secondary server or its doing a zone transfer its literally using that DNS server's database right?

Edit: All DCs are running DNS and DNS is AD integrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the DC boots up it goes across the WAN to pull down the DNS zone from the DNS server in the central office.

AD integrated DNS server replicate the DNS zone information through Active Directory replication, as the zone information is actually stored in Active Directory. When the DC boots up it replicates all AD information, including the DNS zones and some files (GPOs, logon/logoff scripts, netlogon share, etc.).

If the branch office DC is *not* hosting DNS, and there is no other AD integrated DNS server at the branch, then all DNS requests are going over the WAN every time there is a request.

Comment: All of our DCs are DNS servers as well

Comment: Then the DNS information is stored in AD and transferred between DNS servers when AD is synchronized. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc772101.aspx

Comment: Right ok I should have been more specific. Apart from regular AD replication of the DNS partition to its partners, it shouldn't have to talk to the server specified as its primary dns server after loading DNS data from it correct?

Comment: If you have configured a server besides 127.0.0.1 as the primary DNS server in any machine's TCP/IP properties, then it will always try to go to that server first for DNS resolution, not to itself or any other server.

Comment: But it will resolve requests from clients pointing to that branch DC as their primary DNS right?

Comment: Yes, and when it resolves them, it will first check locally (on itself), and then go to any forwarders, and go to root hints. It will only go to another AD integrated server if that other server is listed as a forwarder, which wouldn't make much sense as they should have identical zone information if everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`When the DC boots up it goes across the WAN to pull down the DNS zone from the DNS server in the central office` - That isn't technically correct. When booting up, a DC will inbound replicate all AD partitions, including AD integrated DNS zones (which are AD partitions when the zone is AD integrated), so the booting DC isn't technically pulling a copy of the DNS zone. It hosts it's own copy of the zone and is authoritative for that copy of the zone. It is inbound replicating all AD partitions, including the DNS zone partitions. It's not a zone transfer in the traditional sense. In fact, zone transfers in the traditional sense do not occur when the AD DNS zone is AD integrated. The AD DNS zone replicates along with all of the other AD partitions during replication.

A DC needs to communicate with other DC's to replicate the AD partitions on an ongoing basis, not just at boot time. All DC's that do not hold the PDC Emulator role also need to communicate with the PDCe on an ongoing basis for time synchronization. Your remote DC needs connectivity to your local DC on an ongoing basis, not just at boot time.